# Spatial operations with JSTS

Tags: leaflet, geojson, leaflet-draw, jsts

I'm working with Leaflet and I'm also working with JSTS to do the spatial operations. In most of the cases I want to create Polygons inside another Polygon Geometry.

In this case the yellow shape is the selection. The light blue line is the polygon that will intersect with the selection (yellow shape) and create the new Polygon Geometry:

[image]

The intersect of both  will create the new blue polygon :

[image]

So far so good. But if we repeat the process and we need to create another Polygon (Note: overlaps are forbidden between blue polygons, if there is any overlap, it will generate the difference):

[image]

Up to this point it seems all is ok, both geometry are created correctly.

[image]

The problem is when I select the bottom blue shape. I can see that geometry didn't generate correctly.

[image]

- I have this code to transform between WKT to geojson. Probably the issue it's here in the precision of my geojson. (I can't paste the code right)

```
    var precisionModel = new jsts.geom.PrecisionModel(1000000000000000000000000)
    var geometryPrecisionReducer = new jsts.precision.GeometryPrecisionReducer(precisionModel)
    var geomFactoryJSTS = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory(precisionModel)
    var geoJSONReader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader()
    var geoJSONWritter = new jsts.io.GeoJSONWriter()
    var readerWKT = new jsts.io.WKTReader(geomFactoryJSTS)
    var isValid = new jsts.operation.valid.IsValidOp()
    readerWKT.read(WKT.GeoJSONtoWKT(geojson[i]))
```

- Other posibility is that my yellow shape is in EPSG25831 and Leaflet transform it 'on the fly'. It is posible that Leaflet forget some precision here?

Anyone has idea how can I fix that?

Comment: If all operations are done with JSTS, problem has nothing to do with Leaflet. Whatever GeoJSON object Leaflet receives, so it will show it. As far as projection is concerned, Leaflet expects GeoJSON data in standard, non projected EPSG:4326.

Comment: does anyone know where the jsts API is located? The most similar thing I have is https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts that redirects me to the JTS API(Java)

Comment: I would recommend turf.js: https://turfjs.org/ for GeoJSON geometry operations. Much simpler and has good docs.